# Generate preview image from Video file?

Tags: php, video, thumbnails, php4

Is there a way in PHP given a video file (`.mov`, `.mp4`) to generate a thumbnail image preview?

Comment: @FrankFarmer That link returns no results because the `thumbnail` tag is invalid.

Answer (score 58):

### Solution #1 (Older) (not recommended)

Firstly install `ffmpeg-php` project (http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/)

And then you can use of this simple code:

```
<?php
$frame = 10;
$movie = 'test.mp4';
$thumbnail = 'thumbnail.png';

$mov = new ffmpeg_movie($movie);
$frame = $mov->getFrame($frame);
if ($frame) {
    $gd_image = $frame->toGDImage();
    if ($gd_image) {
        imagepng($gd_image, $thumbnail);
        imagedestroy($gd_image);
        echo '<img src="'.$thumbnail.'">';
    }
}
?>
```

**Description:** This project use binary extension `.so` file, It's very old and last update was for 2008. So, maybe don't works with newer version of `FFMpeg` or `PHP`.

---

### Solution #2 (Update 2018) (recommended)

Firstly install `PHP-FFMpeg` project (https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg)
*(just run for install: `composer require php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg`)*

And then you can use of this simple code:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$sec = 10;
$movie = 'test.mp4';
$thumbnail = 'thumbnail.png';

$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();
$video = $ffmpeg->open($movie);
$frame = $video->frame(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds($sec));
$frame->save($thumbnail);
echo '<img src="'.$thumbnail.'">';
```

**Description:** It's newer and more modern project and works with latest version of `FFMpeg` and `PHP`. Note that it's required to `proc_open()` PHP function.

Comment: The API has changed and this answer needs an update ;)

Comment: @tobias47n9e I checked again, but the old url well works! and also the API not changed (last update of project was for 2008) anyway I added new better solution.

Comment: Remember: This library requires a working FFMpeg install. You will need both FFMpeg and FFProbe binaries to use it. (My hoster does not allow installation of own binaries.)

Comment: @SarahTrees Sure. Try to upload binary ffmpeg and config with `FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create(array(
    'ffmpeg.binaries'  => '/opt/local/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg',
    'ffprobe.binaries' => '/opt/local/ffmpeg/bin/ffprobe',` maybe works.

Comment: Binaries found on https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html for Windows, Linux, OS X ...

Comment: I am facing this error, Can anyone help
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Alchemy\BinaryDriver\Exception\ExecutableNotFoundException' with message 'Executable not found, proposed : avprobe, ffprobe' in D:\Projects\wamp\www\code_build\PHP-FFMpeg-master\src\FFMpeg\Driver\FFProbeDriver.php on line 50`

Answer (score 9):

Two ways come to mind:

- Using a command-line tool like the popular [**ffmpeg**](http://ffmpeg.org/), however you will almost always need an own server (or a very nice server administrator / hosting company) to get that
- Using the "[**screenshoot**](http://www.longtailvideo.com/addons/plugins/102/Screenshoot?q=)" plugin for the [**LongTail Video player**](http://www.longtailvideo.com/) that allows the creation of  manual screenshots that are then sent to a server-side script.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [php-ffmpeg](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg#extracting-image) library.

> **Extracting image**
>
> You can extract a frame at any timecode using the
>   `FFMpeg\Media\Video::frame` method.
>
> This code returns a `FFMpeg\Media\Frame` instance corresponding to the
>   second 42. You can pass any `FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode` as argument,
>   see dedicated documentation below for more information.

```
$frame = $video->frame(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(42));
$frame->save('image.jpg');
```

If you want to extract multiple images from the video, you can use the following filter:

```
$video
    ->filters()
    ->extractMultipleFrames(FFMpeg\Filters\Video\ExtractMultipleFramesFilter::FRAMERATE_EVERY_10SEC, '/path/to/destination/folder/')
    ->synchronize();

$video
    ->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264(), '/path/to/new/file');
```

By default, this will save the frames as **jpg** images.

You are able to override this using `setFrameFileType` to save the frames in another format:

```
$frameFileType = 'jpg'; // either 'jpg', 'jpeg' or 'png'
$filter = new ExtractMultipleFramesFilter($frameRate, $destinationFolder);
$filter->setFrameFileType($frameFileType);

$video->addFilter($filter);
```