# Convert video to image sequences

Tags: php, html, image, video, jpeg

I have developed a html5 app, which one record video around 20 sec in a function. I need to convert this video to image sequences. Then I will display this sequences to my app for further processing. I have a server to upload the videos. I am using php as server scripting language.

**Is there any way to convert video to image (any type jpg, gif, png etc...) sequences using php?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Generate preview image from Video file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043007/php-generate-preview-image-from-video-file)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043007/php-generate-preview-image-from-video-file Looks like a duplicate...have you used the search function?

Comment: Hi, thanks for comment. In that post it was only for preview, but I need image sequences of full video.

Comment: It seems you can use ImageMagick to convert videos to images:
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/video/

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it now, but try to use ffmpeg to convert a video to image sequences:
[How to extract images from a Video using FFmpeg](http://linuxers.org/tutorial/how-extract-images-video-using-ffmpeg)

You'd do something like this:

```
$command = 'ffmpeg -i '
           . escapeshellarg($videoFilePath)
           . ' -r 1 -f image2 '
           . escapeshellarg($dstDirPath)
           . '/image-%3d.jpeg';
exec($command, $output, $return);
```

Comment: Is shared hosting support ffmpeg?

Comment: Usually shared hostings don't support ffmpeg, though some support it, such as TMDHosting and Arvixe support it for a low price (4$/month), but maybe you to use it as a web service: http://ffmpeg.io/server (I never used it).