# How to get the thumbnail of a video file using php and save it as a jpg?

Tags: php, image, video-capture

(Is it possible to get the thumbnail of a video file (stored on the server) using php and save it as a jpg image)?how:return;

Comment: Take a look here [Generate preview image from video file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043007/generate-preview-image-from-video-file)

Comment: @TanuelMategi Thanks, seems very useful.

Comment: Take a look at http://ffmpeg.org/ along with this discussion http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10327812-How-to-install-ffmpeg-php-to-create-thumbnails-from-videos