# Better way for Video Streaming stored on firebase storage on Web application

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, angularfire2

I am building a web application using angular and firebase. Videos are stored on Firebase storage. Now I display the number of videos and when the specific video is selected, it is then played.

There are many videos on the web app and all the videos are displayed on thumbnails and for that I am using the url i.e. `downloadURL`s of the videos.

[image]

The problem is that, all the videos have to be loaded to display the video thumbnails and since each videos have large size, around `20-25 mb`, it takes lots of time to load all the videos.

Please let me know any better solution. Thank you

Comment: create thumbnail  as image manually and store it along with the record,

Comment: @rashidnk Thank you for the message. I was thinking of the same idea. But just wanted to know is this the way all the video streaming app does??

Comment: Yes, check youtube thumbnail with inspect tool, it shows <img tag with jpg url, but the thumbnail is generated with programmaticaaly, not manual

Comment: also u can try some services, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043007/generate-preview-image-from-video-file

Comment: @rashidnk I will definitely take a look. Really appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: welcome, u can vote up my comment if its helpful