# create image from video dynamically

Tags: php, image, video

I want to display images from videos stored in the Website folder.

Instead on the white boxes below I want to view an image of each video:

[image]

***What is the best direct way to do so?***

Comment: Have your tried googling?? https://stackoverflow.com/q/2043007 is the first result for the query `php preview image from video`....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate preview image from Video file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043007/generate-preview-image-from-video-file)

Comment: I did and I couldn't understand people codes, thanks man I'll check this

Comment: https://github.com/lcherone/php-ffmpeg-thumbnail-example