# IE hangout when loading many video tags

Tags: php

I have developed a page to load many videos "27 for example".
In Chrome all videos are loading but in IE some are not loading "showed" in the page.

I did this instead of showing a thumbnail of each video. because I have never did that and I don't know how to do? also didn't understand [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043007/generate-preview-image-from-video-file)

Here's my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["user_role"])) {
header("Location:login.php");
exit();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>xxx</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="enStyle.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header"><img id="all" src="logo.png" alt="xxx"/> </div>
  <div id="row">
    <h3 class="title">xxx</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="menu-wrapper">
      <ul class="nav">
        <?php
if(isset($_SESSION["user_role"]) && $_SESSION["user_role"] =='admin')
{
echo '<li><a href="adminIndex.php"><img src="setting.png" alt="Home Page" style="width:24px;height:24px;border:0;margin:15px 15px 15px 0;">Control Panel</a></li>';
}
else
{
echo '<li><a href="login.php"><img src="setting.png" alt="Home Page" style="width:24px;height:24px;border:0;margin:15px 15px 15px 0;">Admin Login</a></li>';
}
?>
        <li><a href="index.php"><img src="icon.png" alt="Home Page" style="width:24px;height:24px;border:0;margin:15px;">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="requestVideo.php"> Request Video</a></li>
        <li class="nav-search">
          <form action="search.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"/>

          <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search here...">
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="">
          </form>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <ul>
        <?php
$dbhost="xxx";
$dbuser="xxx";
$con = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser, "xxx");
if (!$con) 
{
  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
}

mysqli_select_db($con,'xxx');
$query ="SELECT * FROM movies";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    if ($result)
    {
        $movie = NULL;
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result))
        {
            while($db_field = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {

                $title = $db_field['title'];
                $mo = $db_field['file'];
                ?>
        <?php echo "<li><a href='playMovie.php?id=".$db_field['ID']."'>".$title."</a>";?>
        <video controls preload id="viewVideo">
          <source src='uploadedMovies/<?php echo $mo;?>' type=video/mp4>
        </video>
        <?php
                echo "</li>";
            }
        }
    }
?>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

***Is there a way to fix this or I must change my method of displaying the videos "using a thumbnail .." ?***

Comment: Loading 27 videos at the same time in a page is not a good idea, because it would take a lot of resources in the client machine, even if the browser doesn't fails you are going to slow down a lot medium to low-end machines. If you are showing more than 2-3 videos it's better using a thumbnail for each video and load it dynamically when the user press the thumbnail.

Comment: @AlbertoMartinez Thank you sir I'll use a thumbnail :)